How to set up lossless settings for convert from Imagemagick ran on colored images with -compress JPEG2000/WebP for PDF/TIFF output?
Continuing Lossless or near lossless compression options for PDFs containing grayscale with JPEG2000? and Which compression modes of convert of imagemagick are lossless (with -quality 100)?, which settings are appropriate for convert from ImageMagick on Debian 12 to get lossless JPEG2000 or WebP compression while producing colored PDF or TIFF files?
So far, I thought that supplying -quality 100 is enough. I though that, for instance,
$ convert page_1.pnm page_2.pnm … page_last.pnm -compress JPEG2000 -quality 100 output.pdf

and
$ convert page_1.pnm page_2.pnm … page_last.pnm -compress WebP -quality 100 output.tiff

don't lose any information while producing the output files. However, I failed to find an independent confirmation of this, so now I'm having second thoughts.
Which settings for JPEG2000 and WebP compression types and PDF and TIFF output do lossless compression? References are welcome.
